# Algebraic topology book after John Lee "Introduction to topological manifolds"

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

What algebraic topology book do you suggest to study after one has studied John Lee's "Introduction to topological manifolds"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also recently finished Lee's book (although I don't believe one can ever "finish" a math textbook) and I'm finding  J.P May's A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology very illuminating 
(it's also available for free [on his website](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKSMaster.html) which is nice).

When I have trouble understanding some passages or I find the motivation for some things lacking (since May's book is indeed quite concise) I usually consult Hatcher who Is significantly more wordy (in my opinion) and is, as I understand it, the standard reference for algebraic topology 
(+ his book can also be found for free on [his website](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/#ATI)). \

I've also found Pierre Schapira's [Lecture notes](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Epierre.schapira/lectnotes/) helpful. He is, like May, a bit heavier on the use of categorical terminology (although I haven't read much thus far, but the little I did get around to read seemed great).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Lee's book.  But if you're ready I know a really good, thorough, algebraic topology book is the one by Spanier.  I had the pleasure to take one of his courses.  Boy was he good.

Munkres and Greenburg and Harper are also both good.